# Why Sleuth doesn't work with Log4j2 in my Spring Boot service

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have one question - why Sleuth doesn't work with Log4j2? I have excluded default logging library and added Log4j2 to use some other features like these in application.properties filr"

```
logging.file=myservice.log
logging.file.max-size= 500MB
logging.file.max-history=14
logging.level.pl.utlimo.*=INFO
```

My pom:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I really spent many hours to find solution for my problem. What should I do to use Log4j2 with Sleuth? Now Sleuth doesn't trace anything.

Thank you very much for your help.
Matthew

Comment: maybe `spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.enabled=true` and log the ids `logging.pattern.level=[%X{X-B3-TraceId}/%X{X-B3-SpanId}] %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n`?

Answer (score 2):

In your log4j2.xml, try to add following.

```
<PatternLayout pattern="[%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{X-B3-TraceId},%X{X-B3-SpanId},%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId},%X{X-Span-Export}] [%p] - %l - %m%n"/>
```

Then for some reason, specify the log4j2.xml path in your application.yml

```
logging.config=path/to/log4j2.xml
```

Good luck!