# To use Sleuth along with log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to get appName, traceid,spanid in my logs using sleuth. I am aware that it can be done using logback. But I am not able to get these using log4j2. Can somebody help me how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried in your log4j ? can you share what you have tried and what is not working ?

Comment: Did you try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774345/spring-cloud-sleuth-log4j2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389110/why-sleuth-doesnt-work-with-log4j2-in-my-spring-boot-service
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822803/how-to-get-trace-id-and-span-id-in-the-log4j2-in-the-format-traceid-spanid

Comment: Yes,but no success.